# List of point into smooth curve (airfoil shape)

Tags: points, solidworks

I have a list of 200 points I garnered from a graph digitization software I would like to transform into a smooth curve and then into Solidworks.

My points form an ellipse (airfoil shape to be more precise), so the commands I've tried in Matlab didn't have a circular curve.

My issues are:
* Obtaining a smooth curve that doesn't necessarily pass through all points, smooth being motus operandi.
* Being able to have a elliptical curve
* Somehow being able to export this curve into Solidwords

If anyone knows the right software, command line or anything that could get me started, I would be extremely thankful.

imacube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Solid Works before. It's a very powerful tool. There should be some way to draw a curved spline through these points, such as a cubic spline.

Comment: http://www.dur.ac.uk/g.l.ingram/download/SolidWorksAerofoilGuide.pdf    Found this link which details the procedure pretty well. The spline editor in Solidworks is not so good though

Comment: It is my experience with such tools that if you are dissatisfied with them, you probably haven't found the best way to understand and use them. This is why I enjoy writing my own programs. I don't have to learn how some other person's program works, and the best way to use it, I can just make my own and it will work how I see fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard(ish) airfoil, then you can use a variety of tools to plot the points without having to use a graph digitization software.

Javafoil, for instance, is one of those. Even if you know the characteristics of your airfoil, you can use this to give you a smooth set of points.

Again, if your airfoil is a naca 4-series, then these are governed by a set of equations.

But I take it that the airfoil you want a more complicated one. Let me know if I can help anymore.